# Table aliasess do not work from php

Tags: php, mysql

What I am tring to do is selecting columns from two mysql tables.
This query does not work from php script (I need s.opis column):

```
$SQL="SELECT h.dzien, h.sektor, s.opis, h.start, h.stop, h.p, h.reg_date FROM harmonogram h,sektory s WHERE h.sektor=s.sektor AND h.dzien='".$dzien."' AND h.start='".$start."' ORDER BY h.dzien, h.sektor, h.start, h.stop;";
$wynik = mysql_query($SQL)
or die('Błąd zapytania');
```

but, when I run SQL on mysql database directly it works fine.

```
mysql> SELECT h.dzien, h.sektor, s.opis, h.start, h.stop, h.p, h.reg_date FROM harmonogram h,sektory s WHERE h.sektor=s.sektor AND h.dzien='Sun' AND h.start='08:00' ORDER BY h.dzien, h.sektor, h.start, h.stop;
+-------+--------+------+----------+----------+---+---------------------+
| dzien | sektor | opis | start    | stop     | p | reg_date            |
+-------+--------+------+----------+----------+---+---------------------+
| Sun   |      1 | tyl  | 08:00:00 | 08:15:00 | 0 | 2017-03-01 20:23:35 |
+-------+--------+------+----------+----------+---+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is a previous versions of a query that works fine but it does not show opis column

```
$SQL="SELECT dzien, sektor, start, stop, p, reg_date FROM harmonogram WHERE dzien='".$dzien."' AND start='".$start."' ORDER BY dzien, sektor, start, stop;";
$wynik = mysql_query($SQL)
or die('Błąd zapytania');
```

I think the problem might be with the aliasess.

Any help on this one please?

Comment: You need to stop using `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated for years and don't even exist in current PHP releases. Please study about  [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), known as PDO for short, for a more modern approach.

Comment: Are you sure the input data is the same? I see interpolation in the SQL string of your PHP script. Also, how are you using the data? How did you concluded that it _"does not work"_? Do you receive any error?

Comment: I echoed $SQL and copy paste it into mysql. I got error message from die command.

Comment: How about if you try and see the error? `$wynik = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Also read up on the use of prepared statements, as your probably using user submitted data in the WHERE clause

Comment: YES, now I think I know the issue. I got SELECT command denied to user 'robot_123'@'localhost' for table 'sektory'. I forgot changing privilages. I will check this and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

adding as MacPrawn suggested

```
$wynik = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());
```

put more light on an error message.

It was mysql table privilages issue.
Now is solved.

Thanks all!